# STUN and TURN Server

Tags: webrtc, stun, turn, peerjs

I have developed a webrtc based video chat using peerjs. The solution is working fine but some users are facing problem to establish the call. I guess it is due to NAT and firewall issues.

I have user peerjs as :

```
var peer = new Peer({host: myserver.com], port: 9000, debug: true});
```

I have changed the code to [passed google stun] as seen here : =

Still the same issue. Some user can not connect to peer id. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What you have done @selbie

Comment: I indented your line of javascript such it appears as a code block.  It makes the question much more readable.

Comment: Also, welcome to the world of P2P and WebRTC, where rarely anything "just works".  Issues like, "why can't I reliably connect" aren't going to be solved by someone inspecting one line of javascript.  It could be a NAT issue.  Could be an issue with another peer.  Either way, you may have to debug very hard with tools such as Wireshark and Fiddler to understand the flow of your network traffic.

Comment: Yes, I'm new to this. For NAT issues, everyone is saying to implement/add the STUN and TURN server. But I dunno how to add this. Could you please tell me how to resolve this issue. @selbie

Comment: Using port 9000 may be your problem, as it may not be accessible due to firewall rules. I presume you have your own peerjs server not at 'myserver.com' but some other address?